# How to set printformatter to automatically detect the pdf pages orientation while printing.(Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview

**Problem Definition:-** I have a pdf of more than 1 page and some of the pages are in landscape orientation and others are in portrait. So I want these to come in their respective orientation while printing.

**Research Done:-** We are using UIWebView for document preview and the preview is coming fine as expected but when I am trying to print the pdf then printinfo is always taking portrait orientation. And, that's where the problem lies, as I want the output to be correctly oriented.